# Tradução de 'keep track'

Tags: tradução-inglês, significado-em-contexto

> Learn other languages ​doing what you like and keep track so you are
> doing it every day.

Estou com muita dificuldade de traduzir esta frase de uma forma melhor adaptável para o português brasileiro. Exemplos como ''Aprenda outros idiomas fazendo o que gosta e 'acompanhe/rastreie/monitore' para que voçê esteja fazendo isso todos os dias'' = péssima tradução.

a expressão ''keep track'' está bastante difícil de adaptar neste contexto específico.

Comment: Vou repetir porque alguém deletou o meu comentário: Esse inglês está muito mal escrito. Acho que tenho o direito de falar sobre a minha própria língua, né? Em geral, se diz: to keep track of something, tipo: and keep track of your progress or make sure you are doing it every day. Nesse caso, não sabemos o que a pessoa vai "keep track of".

Comment: Sim, como voce disse que a escrita estava ruim talvez isso explique porque tive tanta dificuldade de  imaginar uma traduçao adaptável para meu idioma, pois "keep track so you're doing it everyday" se tratava de uma fala de uma youtuber que estava dando dicas de como aprender outros idiomas de maneira  mais eficaz. De qualquer maneira seu comentario contribuiu muito para enriquecer esse tópico. Quanto ao fato de seu comentario ter sido excluído eu realmente nao sei o que aconteceu.

Comment: Você deveria ter mencionado que apareceu em Youtube. O contexto é tudo em tradução. :)

Answer (score 1):

Possíveis traduções de 'keep track':

- Acompanhar
- Controlar
- Manter o controle
- Ficar de olho (mais informal)
- Rastrear
- Observar
- Monitorar

No caso desta frase, talvez ***"monitorar"*** e ***"acompanhar"*** sejam as mais adequadas para manter o sentido original. Mas como você as descartou,  vou dar três outras sugestões.

Mais formal:

> Aprenda idiomas fazendo o que gosta e **assegure-se** de fazê-lo todos os dias.

Mais informal:

> Aprenda idiomas fazendo o que gosta e **fique de olho** para manter o ritmo.

Eu particularmente não gosto muito dessa forma de imperativo para a linguagem informal, então se for realmente informal e se for uma chamada, poderia ser:

> Comece a aprender idiomas fazendo o que gosta e mantendo um ritmo diário de estudo!

Comment: @Southman Responda então, por favor, sua própria pergunta!

Comment: Bem lembrado, amigo. Já fiz a correção.

Answer (score 1):

Após uma conversa com uma nativa da língua inglesa entendi que a expressão ''keep track'' neste contexto específico tem o mesmo sentido da expressão ''keep a record''. A sugestão foi que a tradução mais próxima seria ''Aprenda inglês fazendo o que gosta e mantenha um cronograma a fim de que voçê esteja fazendo isso todos os dias'', ou ''aprenda inglês fazendo o que gosta e acompanhe seu desempenho fazendo isso todos os dias''.